# Can we use appositives befor the subject?

Tags: grammar

1) Good vocabulary, knowledge
of grammar, sense of style--all
are basic writing skills. 2) Basic
writing skills--good vocabulary,
knowledge of grammar, sense
of style-- can be learned by
almost everyone. In (2) the
series of appositives are "good
vocabulary, knowledge of
grammar, sense of style". So by
definition "The appositive is a
noun or noun phrase that
modifies another noun" so it
means appositive comes after
the subject right? But my doubt
is can we use appostives before
a subject like in (1) and in (1)
which is the subject(i.e noun)
that modifies the noun phrases
"Good vocabulary, knowledge of
grammar, sense of style" ?

Answer (score 1):

'Appositive' means 'side by side', but as its purpose is to give additional information, the more definite noun phrase will usually come first (so we could call the extra info postpositive).
In (1), the list is the subject and 'all' is the postpositive (all [of the preceeding items]).

"My brother, Allen" and "Allen, my brother" both have equal 'definiteness'.

"My brother, a doctor" works, but *"A doctor, my brother" is weak because the definiteness increases in the postpositive.

Comment: Only specifying NPs can be appositives. In "my brother, a doctor", the NP "a doctor" is ascriptive, not specifying, and hence is not an appositive. The OP's first example is not an appositive at all. The second is an appositive construction where "good vocabulary, knowledge of grammar, sense of style" are supplementary appositive NPs anchored to (but not modifying) the NP "basic writing skills".

Comment: @BillJ - Are you not recognizing non-restrictive appositions?  And do you not allow pronouns in appositions?